# grep POSIX regex match Hindi and Japanese

Tags: regex, linux, posix

I try the following `echo 'ひらが' | grep '[[:alnum:]]'` and it matched the string.

but my locale shows English:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

shouldn't [:alnum:] match language thats set in locale, whats happening here?

Comment: You are asking different questions in the title and in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post this as a partial answer, since I spent some time digging up these information, and it's too long for a comment.

If you take a look at the locale definition files located at `/usr/share/i18n/locales` on Linux installation, we can find that the definition of `LC_CTYPE` (which defines the classification of the characters, as used by `ctype.h` in C and POSIX character class) in `en_US` copies the definition from `en_GB`, and `LC_CTYPE` definition in `en_GB` copies the definition from `i18n`, with minor additions.

Looking at the file `i18n`, the bulk of `LC_CTYPE` definition is here. We can see that `alpha` includes letters of all languages defined in Unicode, with the following comment briefly explaining the rationale:

```
% The "alpha" class of the "i18n" FDCC-set is reflecting
% the recommendations in TR 10176 annex A
alpha /
```

Annex A of the standard [ISO/IEC TR 10176 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG20/docs/n927-tr10176-2002.pdf) seems to recommend to use an "extended repertoire for user-defined identifier", which is supposed "to improve understandability for programmers whose native language is not English", though I fail to see how it has anything to do with the definition of `alpha` character class.